# Make a specific column of a datagrid Read Only in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created an ObservableCollection, this ObservableCollection contains a classtype that contains multiple properties.
Then I have added stuff into this ObservableCollection when the program starts.
Then I have bound a datagrid on de xaml file to this ObservableCollection. So now the datagrid shows everything inside the ObservableCollection.

I want to make the first column a readonly column. Here is the xaml code:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsDG1}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="false" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="false" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600" Margin="0,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" SelectionUnit="Cell" MaxWidth="193" MaxHeight="600" FontSize="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyBackground, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is the constructor:

```
 public Entry128OutputsViewModel(Entry128OutputsView entry128outputsview)//contructor, dient voor de Mainwindow te linken met de properties van deze klasse.
    {
        ItemsDG1 = new ObservableCollection<DataTableOutputs>() { };
        ItemsDG2 = new ObservableCollection<DataTableOutputs>() { };

        FillInDataGrids();
    }
```

Here is my method for filling the datagrids:

```
enter codepublic void FillInDataGrids()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 33; i++)
        {
            ItemsDG1.Add(new DataTableOutputs { Nr = Convert.ToString(i), A = false, D = false, CommandAdd = "0/0/0", ReturnAdd = "0/0/0" });
        }
        for (int i = 33; i < 65; i++)
        {
            ItemsDG2.Add(new DataTableOutputs { Nr = Convert.ToString(i), A = false, D = false, CommandAdd = "0/0/0", ReturnAdd = "0/0/0" });
        }
    } here
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `IsReadOnly` [property of column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.isreadonly?view=net-5.0) you want